# Ionic 3 break data and show or angular trunk option

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am fetching some data from api, but their are some wordings, which are in single string. I need to show them seperately. Here is how it come in console:

[image]

And i want to show in my app like this:

[image]

This is already showing in other mobile application like this. But i want to know how it will done with ionic angular.

This is how im showing wording .

```
.ts
 this.wording = this.res[0].policywording;

 .html
 <div *ngIf="wording">{{wording}}</div>
```

and the output is same as in console which is not in sequence i want to show it like as i attach . I think it is possible by trunk but dont know how ill use it .

Comment: Please, show us what you've been trying.

Comment: i show in question the data is showing in string i need to break down and show like in sequence as attach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to break up that data. Something like this:

ts:

```
this.displayData = [];
if (this.wording) {
  const policies = this.wording.split('|').filter(w => w !== '');
  this.displayData = [];
  policies.forEach((policy) => {
    const splited = policy.split('=');
    const displayPolicy = {name: splited[0], value: splited[1]};
    this.displayData.push(displayPolicy);
  });
}
```

.html:

```
<div *ngIf="displayData && displayData.length > 0">
 <div *ngFor="let policy of displayData">{{policy.name:}} {{policy.value}}</div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!displayData || displayData.length === 0">No Data available</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working . can you please tell me what is the code if data is null its showing error "Can not read property split of null" Because data is null . if data is null so it just show no data found . Thanks again

Comment: Just check with an if in .ts and with an *ngIf in .html. You can put *ngIf on every html element, not only divs.

Comment: I already updated my code in the answer. Was that not what you needed? See the if (this.wording) in .ts code and *ngIf in .html code